# Как вытащить данные с массива

Tags: python, python-3.x

Функция возвращает значения вида `[<Container: 09c99d59d4>]` как мне достать значение 09c99d59d4?

Comment: Смотря что за класс-контейнер. Можно конечно элемент списка к строке привести, потом вытащить значение регулярным выражением, но это как-то не совсем правильно.

Comment: `hex(id(your_list[0]))`.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю что <Container: 09c99d59d4> это инстанс класса Container. Попробуйте посмотреть методы **str** и **repr** - вероятнее всего в них есть переменная которая отвечает за искомое значение.